# find the frequency of elements in a java array

Tags: java

I have an int array:

```
{1,2,4,2,3,5,6,4,3}
```

How can I find frequencies of array elements like `1=1,2=2,3=2,4=4..`. I need a class which I can pass my array to and return an array which gives the count of array elements. ex:- `array{[0]=1,[1]=2,[2]=3,[3]=4..}` (for above example array);

Comment: Smells like like homework

Comment: What have you [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: `Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(...), X)`

Comment: "Give me teh codez" questions are discouraged.

Comment: @oldrinb , Could you please have a look and check why this piece of code does not work? http://ideone.com/QZD5jp (It gives zero for every number)

Comment: @Hengameh `Arrays.asList(int[])` without using varargs will treat the argument as a single `int[]` object and return a singleton `List<int[]>`. either pass them directly using varargs or pass around `Integer[]` to allow individual boxing of the elements -- http://ideone.com/TwS3yJ

Answer (score 8):

```
class MapTest
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> h = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        int arr[] = new int[]{2,2,3,3,5,6,7,9,9,0};
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(h.containsKey(arr[i])){
                h.put(arr[i], h.get(arr[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                h.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most elite solution before java8. I still prefer it.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8 you can do this

```
Map<Integer, Long> freq = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Isn't is enough to just  use `Function.identity()` instead of `Integer::intValue`? We don't really need to unbox an integer in this case

Comment: @Anton Yes, it should work while I'm not sure how much it saves.

Comment: If you have java 8 you can just use [Collections#frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 3):

You have to do a few things:

1. Define an upper and lower bound for your range of numbers.
2. Establish a convenient object/data structure to store occurrences of these numbers.
3. Iterate through the passed-in array and count all occurrences of each number, storing the result in the convenient object/data structure.

If this is done in a simple manner, it could be only a matter of reading the elements from the passed-in array and printing out the final result.

Answer (score 3):

Using Java-8 we can find the frequency of an array in a single line.

```java
Map<Integer, Long> freq = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().
                          collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Also, since the question demands we need to return an array

```java
public Object[] getFrequencies(int[] a) {
    Map<Integer, Long> freq = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    return freq.entrySet().toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If range of the elements of the array is specified and limited to array size, the best solution is using hash map.
T(n) = O(n), auxiliary space = O(n).

```
public static void findCount3(int[] a){
    Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();     
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if(!hm.containsKey(a[i])){
               hm.put(a[i], 1);
            }else{
               hm.put(a[i], hm.get(a[i])+1);
    }               
    System.out.println(hm);         
}
```

Comment: why first for loop is required?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
class Findfreqarray
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int t, i, j, len, count=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements to insert in an array: ");
        len = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        System.out.println("Enter elements to insert in an array: ");
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            t = in.nextInt();
            arr[i] = t;
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            count=1;
            for(j=i+1;j<=len-1;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j] && arr[i]!='\0')
                {
                    count++;
                    arr[j] = '\0';
                }
            }
            if(arr[i]!='\0')
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i] + " is " + count + " times.\n");
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813907/avoid-count-same-element-in-array-java#comment121632421_68813907), this fails if the input array contains more than one 0.

Comment: I recommend adding a boolean array that will track which elements have already been counted instead of modifying the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving it away here is a good starting point:

```
int[] array = {1,2,4,2,3,5,6,4,3};

        public int[] (array){
            //need to perform a sort...or a search
            //after searching check for matches,
            //sorting could make performing comparisons more efficient
            //not all searches/sorts are created equal.

            int[array.length] result += {"["+numberChecked+"]="+freqOccurred};
            return result;
        }
```

This code is has not been compiled so think of it more as psuedocode.  The purpose is to get you thinking about how to achieve the desired goal.  An java package may already exist that can check the frequency elements in an array, but this is what you are most likely looking for.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for count the frequency of elements in a java array

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ItemCount {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
            int count=1,index=1;
            BufferedReader  br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter the Size of array : ");
            int size=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter the Elements of array : ");
            int arr[]=new int[size];

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print("arr["+i+"] :  ");
                arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
            System.out.print("Sorted Array is :");
            SortingArray.sortDescendind(arr);

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("arr["+i+"] :  "+arr[i]);

            }

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;)
            {
                count=1;
                for(index=i+1;index<arr.length;index++)
                {
                    if(arr[i]==arr[index])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else{

                        break;
                    }


                }
                System.out.println(""+arr[i] +"----> "+count);
                i+=count;

            }

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

/// you  can select any sorting method for array---->SortingArray.sortDescendind(arr)

Comment: Time complexity of your solution is O(n^2), which is not optimal.

Comment: @hengameh, just a guess but wouldn't the best time complexity be O(n) because you have to read the array at least once?  @JavaFun, **tl;dr** but the fastest way to do it (I think) would be to make a two dimensional counting array and read the original array once.  As you read the array, each time you come across a new element in the array, add `{ element, occurrences}` to the counting array, and if you come across an old element, just add one to its occurrences spot

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the frequency of each element in a HashMap<Element,Frequency>.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
int arr[] = new int[]{2,2,3,3,5,6,7,9,9,0};

for(int elem:arr) {
  h.merge(elem, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Hashmap.merge() lets you specify how to update the value in the hashmap. If there is no existing value for elem, it will be similar to h.put(elem, 1). If there is an existing value, called oldFreq, it will replace it with Integer.sum(oldFreq, 1)

Comment: Updated. It's similar to Ankit's solution, but it's more concise. I don't think it has any limitations

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
int arr[] = new int[]{2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 0, 4, 2};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Integer count = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0);
    map.put(arr[i], count + 1);
}

//Print the map to see the occurrence
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println(key + " -> " + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package practice.learning;

import java.util.Arrays;
public class FreqElem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] names= {"Pawan","Rohan","Sudesh","Pawan","Shiv"};

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
            int count=0;
            //System.out.print(names[i]);
            String a=names[i];
            for(int j=0;j<names.length;j++) {
                if(names[j]==a) {
                    count+=1;
                }
                
                
            }
            System.out.println(names[i]+":"+count); 
        }
        
    }

}
```

> Output:
> Pawan:2
> Rohan:1
> Sudesh:1
> Pawan:2
> Shiv:1