# How to count the frequency of each number in an array based on user input

Tags: java, arrays

i just started learning java and was hoping i could get some help on a logical problem im having. My goal is to as user to enter multiple numbers into an array. I then request the user to insert number from their initial input and print the frequency of that number compared to their first input. I have searched for some time and all the explanations are beyond my level so if anyone could reduce the explanation to a dummy level that will be great.

```
public class numberCounting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] storage = new int[100];
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("How many total enteries?");
        int total = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + i + " number");
            int entry = input.nextInt();
            storage[i] = entry;

        }
        System.out.println("what number do you want to count the frequency of?: ");
        int frequency = input.nextInt();
        for (int x : frequency) {
            if (x == x) {
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("There are " + counter + "repeats of your number");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kev. Please check out [ask], then come back and edit your question accordingly. As is, you're pretty much asking us to solve the assignment for you. Instead, you should narrow down what _exactly_ your issue is, then ask a _specific_ question about that issue.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't create your `storage` array with a fixed size of `100` and then ask the user for the amount of entries. You should ask first and use *that number* as the size, e.g. `int total = input.nextInt(); int[] storage = new int[total];`. Otherwise you risk getting a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also in Java, indices start at `0`, so your first for loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {`

Comment: This question is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207483/find-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-java-array

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the wrong input and on top of that you are looping wrongly. Does it even compile? Change it to that

```
for (int x: storage) {
    if (x == frequency) counter++;
}
```

Besides that - an array starts at the zero index. You are skipping the first entry by setting `i = 1`.