# Java method to specifically check if an array has an element that is duplicated four times

Tags: java, arrays, loops, duplicates

I have an Array with an element size of 5 and I'm trying to write a java method that will find if four of the elements are duplicates. How can this be done? One example of this, let's say I have 5 dice. I want to know if four of them are the same number.

Comment: You're essentially trying to find the [frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207483/find-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-java-array) of all elements, and check if one occurs four times.

Answer (score 0):

I would use streams, like this:

```
<T> boolean checkForFourDuplicates(T[] x) {
    return Arrays.stream(x)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(count -> count == 4);
}
```