# Finding duplicated values in array and remove both of them?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

OK I know for Set and how to remove duplicated items from list,

```
Set<Integer> setint = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(int j=0;j<selectedList.size();j++){
    setint.add(selectedList.get(j));
}
```

but what I need is to remove both of them.
For example if I have `1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9`
what I need is to find what integers are duplicated and remove both value. So for this example I want to remove 3 and 7, so that I have new array `1,2,4,5,6,8,9`.

Comment: Pass all values to a hashtable/HashMap and count frequency. If the frequency is greater than 1. You iterate over the array and remove all values.

Comment: [Frequency of element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207483/find-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-java-array/23599615). You should be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Logics**

ex: `ar=[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]`

first copy duplicate values to another array and remove it
now you got  `ar_removed=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]`

here another array you got  `ar_dup=[3,7]`

now check with `ar_removed` and `ar_dup`

you can remove `ar_dup` values by condition. The result `ar_fi=[1,2,4,5,6,8,9]`

may it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the duplicates into a `Set`, then use `list.removeAll(set)` to remove all duplicate occurrences

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
        add(3);
        add(4);
        add(5);
        add(6);
        add(7);
        add(7);
        add(7);
        add(8);
        add(9);
    }};

    // Sort the list to have adjacent duplicates 
    ArrayList<Integer> templist = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(templist);

    // Get the duplicate numbers
    Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < templist.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (templist.get(i).equals(templist.get(i + 1)))
            duplicates.add(templist.get(i));
    }

    // Remove the duplicates
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCreate: " + list);
    list.removeAll(duplicates);
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCreate: " + list);
```

Result:

```
D/LOG_TAG: onCreate: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9]
D/LOG_TAG: onCreate: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```