# avoid count same element in array java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, logic

```
// Repetaded element run multiple times means avoid duplicate element count multiple times

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindFrequency {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int t,  count=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements to insert in an array: ");
      int  len = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[len];
        System.out.println("Enter elements to insert in an array: ");
        for( int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            t = in.nextInt();
            arr[i] = t;
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            count=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<=len-1;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j] )
                {
                    count++;
                 }
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " is " + count + " times.\n");
            }        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specify better your question and edit it for better understanding

Comment: the duplicate element of array  run multiple times.      Enter number of elements to insert in an array: 
5
Enter elements to insert in an array: 
1
2
1
2
6


1 is 2 times.

2 is 2 times.

1 is 1 times.

2 is 1 times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find the frequency of elements in a java array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207483/find-the-frequency-of-elements-in-a-java-array)

Comment: NO, without using predefined class and methods of java

Comment: if you enter 0 more than 1 time as array element  it gives no output . it will work for non zero array element. for example {1,0,1,0,5}.

Answer (score -1):

I have used one more array to store the print value.We can use set as well as.I hope you get the answer.

```
let array = [1,2,1,3,4,5,6,2]
var arrayWithPosition = [Int]()

for i in 0..<array.count {
    var position = 0
    while position < arrayWithPosition.count {
        if arrayWithPosition[position] == array[i]{
            break
        }
        position += 1
    }
    if position == arrayWithPosition.count{
        arrayWithPosition.append(array[i])
    }else{
        continue
    }
    var count = 1
    for j in i+1..<array.count {
        if array[i] == array[j] {
            count += 1
        }
    }
    print(array[i],count)
}
```

Output : -

```
1 2
2 2
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
```

Comment: This isn't Java. -1

Comment: Logic matters. He can chage to java.